# How to add specific class to anchor tag has href equal to URL using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, anchor

I want to have a jQuery dynamic menu that navigates to the `<a></a>` tags and the one that include with the  page URL.

```js
$('ul.nav.navbar-nav.side-nav.nicescroll-bar li').find('a').each(function() {
  var text = $(this).attr("href");
  if (window.location.href.includes(text)) {
    $('ul.nav.navbar-nav.side-nav.nicescroll-bar li a').addClass('active')
  } else {}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav side-nav nicescroll-bar" style="overflow: hidden; width: auto; height: 100%;">
  <li><a href="home">home</a></li>
  <li><a href="dashboard">dashboard</a></li>
  <li><a href="base">base</a></li>
  <li><a href="test">test</a></li>
</ul>
```

In this code, there is a color change in all menus, which should change the color of the menu according to the page's address.

Comment: What is question? It doesn't work?

Comment: This code is not required by me. I want a code to color the case that links to the page address or adds a class to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just remove the class in else:

```
if (window.location.href.includes(text)) {
  $(this).addClass('active')
} else {
  $(this).removeClass('active')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
if (window.location.href.includes(text)) {
  $('ul.nav.navbar-nav.side-nav.nicescroll-bar li a').addClass('active')
}
```

into

```
if (window.location.href.includes(text)) {
  $(this).addClass('active')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It works when you use this to add the class. I changed one href to stack because the href of the snippet is something like stacksnippet. For that element it colors red.

```js
$('ul.nav.navbar-nav.side-nav.nicescroll-bar li').find('a').each(function() {
  var text = $(this).attr("href");
  if (window.location.href.includes(text)) {
    $(this).addClass('active')
  }
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav side-nav nicescroll-bar" style="overflow: hidden; width: auto; height: 100%;">
  <li><a href="home">home</a></li>
  <li><a href="dashboard">dashboard</a></li>
  <li><a href="stack">base</a></li>
  <li><a href="test">test</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your selector and code and use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) instead of `.each()`

```
$('ul.navbar-nav li a').filter(function(){
  return window.location.href.includes($(this).attr('href'));
}).addClass('active');
```

```js
window.location.href = "#home";
$('ul.navbar-nav li a').filter(function(){
  return window.location.href.includes($(this).attr('href'));
}).addClass('active');
```

```css
.active {color:red}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav side-nav nicescroll-bar" style="overflow: hidden; width: auto; height: 100%;">
  <li><a href="home">home</a></li>
  <li><a href="dashboard">dashboard</a></li>
  <li><a href="base">base</a></li>
  <li><a href="test">test</a></li>
</ul>
```